# problem putting different outputs into one array/hashtable in powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to get info on the status of several Exchange DBs on several Exchange servers using `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $ExchSvr` into one neat table in powershell.

so you get given this for each server:

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| DB1 | Mounted |
| DB2 | Healthy |
| ... | ... |

and I just want to combine them and output it like this:

| Name | Exch Svr1 | Exch Svr2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DB1 | Mounted | Healthy | ... |
| DB2 | Healthy | Mounted | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm getting the server and database names with the following:

```
$ExchSvrs = (Get-ExchangeServer).name
$DBs = (get-mailboxdatabase).name
```

I'm struggling on the actual meat of it though as my first instinct is to create objects for each DB in a foreach loop and add a property for each exchange server then fill those in from a `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $ExchSvr` for each server. I understand that creating objects in a loop is discouraged so didn't do that.

I tried doing a hashtable of hashtables as that makes it easy to create the hashtables first then fill in the sections in a second loop but couldn't find an easy way to output that to a table without just going element by element through them which seems inefficient.

Next I just did an arraylist with new unnamed objects for each DB but then found it difficult to populate the properties of each object as each server has different DBs on it so I had to use where object every time which seemed really slow.

I feel like I'm fighting against powershell to do this but surely there's an easy way that I'm missing.  I'll appreciate any help I can get and I'm happy to add any more info that people need.

Comment: So `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $ExchSvr` gives you the very top output?

Comment: Where does "exch 1" & "exch2" come from?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear I'm looping through all servers ```foreach($ExchSvr in $ExchSvrs){Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $ExchSvr}``` which gives me the top output for each server so exchange server 1, 2, 3 etc (Exch Svr1, Exch Svr2, Exch Svr3, etc) I'm generating the top output once for each server and want to combine all those outputs into one table with a column for each exchange server and a row for each database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by organizing the status information in a nested hashtable:

```
# Discover all servers
$ExchServers = Get-ExchangeServer

# Create the "outer" table
$statusTable = @{}

# Fetch mailbox db copy status per server, store each copy status as an entry in an inner table
foreach($server in $ExchServers){
  # Create new inner table for this particular server
  $statusTable[$server.Name] = @{}

  foreach($dbCopyStatus in Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $server){
    # Populate inner table
    $statusTable[$server.Name][$dbCopyStatus.Name] = $dbCopyStatus.Status
  }
}
```

Now we just need to transform the data into the desired format - one object per DB, with separate properties for each hosting server:

```
$outputPerDB = foreach($db in Get-MailboxDatabase){
  # create a table to hold the properties on the object we're about to create
  $properties = [ordered]@{ Name = $db.Name }
  foreach($server in $ExchServers){
    # grab property name from server, grab status from status table
    $properties[$server.Name] = $statusTable[$server.Name][$db.Name]
  }

  # turn property table into custom object
  [pscustomobject]$properties
}
```

The resulting objects will now be formatted as you expect:

```
PS ~> $outputPerDB |Format-List

Name ExchSrv1 ExchSrv2
---- -------- --------
DB1  Mounted  Healthy
DB2  Healthy  Mounted
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looping through a set of databases, then looping through all the $ExchSvrs in that database, you'd want to do something like this:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $outputTable = @()

foreach ($dbServer in $dbServers) {
    $obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Name = $dbServer.Name
    }

    foreach ($ExchSvr in $ExchSvrs) {
        $status = Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Server $ExchSvr
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $ExchSvr.Name -NotePropertyValue $status
    }

    $outputTable += $obj
}

$outputTable
```

However, for the table to align properly ALL $ExchSvrs would have to be the same for each database. If the $ExchSvrs for each database row are different, you'll have to do some additional work to reuse $obj and check to see if the member already exists or not.